# Setting label positions with an automatic script

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var s1 = textBox1.Width / 2;
            var s2 = textBox1.Height / 2;

            noprojectslbl.Visible = true;
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
        }
```

The text of the labels will start from the center top left to bottom right.

This screenshot is an example of what I mean.
The top label - label1, should be in the middle, above the two smaller labels 2 and 3, and all this group of labels should be in the center of the textBox.

[image: Example]

Comment: Can you make the label full width and choose center-alignment for the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the Labels and the TextBox are contained directly by the FORM, try something like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.SizeChanged += (s, e) => { UpdateLabelPositions(); };
        textBox1.LocationChanged += (s, e) => { UpdateLabelPositions(); };
        this.Shown += (s, e) => { UpdateLabelPositions(); };
    }

    private void UpdateLabelPositions()
    {
        var s1 = textBox1.Left + textBox1.Width / 2;
        var s2 = textBox1.Top + textBox1.Height / 2;

        noprojectslbl.Visible = true;
        label1.Visible = true;
        label2.Visible = true;

        var totalHeight = noprojectslbl.Bounds.Height + label1.Bounds.Height + label2.Bounds.Height;
        noprojectslbl.Location = new Point(s1 - noprojectslbl.Width / 2, s2 - totalHeight / 2);
        label1.Location = new Point(s1 - label1.Width / 2, noprojectslbl.Bounds.Bottom);
        label2.Location = new Point(s1 - label2.Width / 2, label1.Bounds.Bottom);
    }

}
```

Code in action:

[image]

If the three Labels are contained directly by a Panel, then change your "s1" and "s2" variables in `UpdateLabelPositions()` to:

```
var s1 = panel1.Width / 2;
var s2 = panel1.Height / 2;
```

Comment: Working great with textbox. And if I wanted to make it with panel instead a textbox ? I tried and it didn't work fine.

Comment: It really depends on what the PARENT of the Labels is.  When trying it with a Panel, are the Labels contained by the Panel or the Form?

Comment: When I'm trying with panel I drag the labels over the panel. How can I make the labels to be contained by the panel ?

Comment: When you drag the labels over the panel and let go, they should automatically become children of the panel.  To verify this is true, drag the top left corner of the panel and see if the labels move with it.  If they do, they are children of the panel.  If they don't move with the panel, then they are probably contained by the form (or some other container).